# How to find a dead end in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

For a project about GPS systems, I'm trying to understand how can we see that there is a dead end thanks to an adjacency matrix.

[image]

I know that the adjacency matrix definition is

> Assumed that $G=(V,E)$ is a simple graph, where $\left|V\right|=n$. Assumed also that the vertices number are arbitrarily numbered $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. The adjacency matrix $A$ of $G$ of this set of vertices is A with
>   $$a_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl} 1 & \mbox{if } (v_i,v_j)\in E \\        0 & \mbox{else.}\end{array}\right.$$

Here is the adjacency matrix I found corresponding on the top and on the side to the vertices $[1,2,9,10,11,12]$:
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

How can I know that some are dead end?

To my mind we can only know that thanks to the

Comment: You can start by realizing that $\: (9,\hspace{-0.03 in}10) \neq (10\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}9) \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Okay, but still, it is a 1 and a 1 in the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Whereas it _should be_ a 1 and a 0 in the adjacency matrix. $\;$

Comment: The adjacency matrix of a directed graph need not be symmetric.  In the scheme you proposed a "dead end" would give a row of all zeros in the adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct adjacency matrix is (observe that this is a *directed* graph)
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$
The rows corresponding to $2$ and $12$ are all zero, indicating that there is no way out.

Comment: I think there is a typo at the last but one row, third column. For the (11-9) relation, shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it is a one as far as it is a double edge.

Answer (score -1):

120002
010000
011221
011121
022112
000001

matrix C 'could' or 'might' apply where:

a. each number (from 1 to 12) is independently self sufficient (i.e. 'on')
b. access to corresponding figures in 'the chain' is possible (via other numbers) - to constitute 'on'
c. a ternary introduction can be applied for direct value relationships. i.e. self sufficient independency (value: 1/on) + direction of travel (using direct access) to another chain figure = 2 (value)

there is probably a better way to express the unique 9 to 11 or 11 to 9 relationship (dual direction / exchange) but i don't have sufficient time to explore that right now.

ta.

Comment: Hi, welcome on the MathSE! I think the OP wants to know a general solution for similar problems, not only for this specific one.